# Suppose $A$ be a $10\times 10$ order matrix and $a_{ii}=\alpha+1$ , $\alpha=?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $10\times 10$ order matrix such that $a_{ij}$=$1$ for $i\neq j$ and$ a_{ii}=\alpha+1$ for $\alpha\ge 0$.Let $ \lambda$  and  $\mu $ be largest and smallest eigenvalues of $A$. If$\lambda+\mu=24$ then $\alpha=?$                           here is my attempt -- according to the question diagonal elements are $\alpha+1$ and remaining entries are 1 then as sum of eigen value =sum of trace $10\alpha+10$=$\lambda+\mu+\sum_{i=2}^9\lambda_i $ suppose $\lambda_1=\mu$ and $\lambda_{10}=\lambda$ then $10\alpha$=$14+\sum_{i=2}^9\lambda_i $ as $\lambda+\mu=24$ but how can I find $\alpha$, is my process is correct? If not then what is the correct process?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of the all ones matrix $J$? Figure that out, and then you can solve this problem also. Hint: any vector with sum of components $=0$ is an eigenvector of $J$ belonging to___

Comment: And what Shaun says. If you can't follow up on my hint, then here's another. What if this were a 2x2, 3x3? Start with a case you **can** solve! Work from there up. Report on your progress here, please! Good luck!

Comment: Putting this on hold, because we really don't want you to just dump your homework here. But, we want you to learn, and use the site for that end. Take my suggestions in that light. Others will give more.

Comment: U mean I should mention my attempt. And this is the reason for my downvote?

Comment: Hey jyrki I have already edited my question remove hold mark

Comment: I don't know about the downvote. Pointless to worry. Good job editing. You see the question was promptly reopened!

Comment: Following my suggestions you can find that $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\cdots=\lambda_9$. Prove that! Hmm. I will let you figure what they are all equal to. Hint: it's either $\lambda$ or $\mu$.